# How to install node-sass without root and problems

Tags: node.js, sass, node-modules, sudo, node-sass

I have a lot of problems with node-sass. I hate node-sass because i cannot install everything. I cannot install ionic4, or nativescript.

I got some errors like the following one:

```
configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/torbengab/Desktop/Projects/HelloNativeScript/my-tab-ng/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/...../node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/...../node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I think it is a root / sudo problem. I tried to uninstall node, npm, sass... but I am to stupid. Nothing works for me.

I really really hope that someone could help me. It is so sad and embarrassing that I have so much problems with sass.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have installed (part of) your project as root, perhaps part using `sudo`, and part as a regular user.

Start by removing the entire `node_modules` directory of your project, as root:

```
sudo rm -fr /Users/torbengab/Desktop/Projects/HelloNativeScript/my-tab-ng/node_modules/
```

(this assumes that you have a proper `package.json` that you can use to re-install all the dependencies of your project)

Next, re-install using `npm install` from the project directory. If you run into problems, don't use `sudo` in the hope that will solve the problem; instead, read the error messages and try to determine what *exactly* could be the cause of the problem. If you can't work it out, search or ask StackOverflow.

FWIW, installing `node-sass` on my Mac works just fine, so it's not an inherent issue with that package.

Answer (score 1):

update latest node-sass

```
npm install node-sass@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```